# How to find all matches

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find all matches in a string for "\abc/something/\abc/" ignoring the something part:

If my string is:

`string str = @"\abc/something\abc/\abc/something\abc/;`

how should I write the pattern so that I get two matches of \abc/something\abc/?

Since using the ^ and $ to define the beginning and end in this case wouldn't work as the entire string does begin and end with that.

Comment: I assume you mean to leave out the escaping, since you're using the alternate string literal declaration that doesn't require escaping the backslash?

The regular expression should just be `@"\abc/"`

Comment: what about \abc/something\abc/   as one match ignoring the something part in a string  like @"\abc/something\abc/\abc/something\abc/" ?

Comment: @sln the question in current state has almost nothing to do with post I've marked as duplicate (17:22 duplicate, 17:39 edit).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out various regex's here: http://regexstorm.net/tester

But it looks like you should just match on `\\abc/`

Answer (score 0):

CaptureCollection should get all the matches in one group,
in one pass.

Either this `(?:.*?(\\\w+/))+` or this `(?:(\\\w+/)|.)+`
as an example.

```
 (?:
      .*? 
      ( \\ \w+ / )                  # (1)
 )+
```

C#

```
string str = @"\\adbc/\\abrc/";
//Regex RxAbc = new Regex(@"(?:(\\\w+/)|.)+");
Regex RxAbc = new Regex(@"(?:.*?(\\\w+/))+");
Match _mAbc = RxAbc.Match(str);
if (_mAbc.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection cc = _mAbc.Groups[1].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", cc[i].Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
\adbc/
\abrc/
```

*edit* - From comment `another example that is like this: @"\abc/something\abc/\abc/somethingELSE\abc/, and return 2 matches of \abc/something\abc/`

```
 # ?:.*?((\\\w+/).*?\2))+ 

 (?:
      .*? 
      (                             # (1 start)
           ( \\ \w+ / )                  # (2)
           .*? 
           \2 
      )                             # (1 end)
 )+
```

C#

```
string str = @"\abcX/somethinghere\abcX/\abcY/there\abcY/\abcZ/\abcZ/";
Regex RxAbc = new Regex(@"(?:.*?((\\\w+/).*?\2))+");
Match _mAbc = RxAbc.Match(str);
if (_mAbc.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection ccAbcToAbc = _mAbc.Groups[1].Captures;
    CaptureCollection ccAbc = _mAbc.Groups[2].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < ccAbcToAbc.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found keyword {0}, in string {1}", ccAbc[i].Value, ccAbcToAbc[i].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Found keyword \abcX/, in string \abcX/somethinghere\abcX/
Found keyword \abcY/, in string \abcY/there\abcY/
Found keyword \abcZ/, in string \abcZ/\abcZ/
```

Same code different input

Input = `@"\abc/somethinghere\abc/\abc/there\abc/\abc/\abc/"`

Output:

```
Found keyword \abc/, in string \abc/somethinghere\abc/
Found keyword \abc/, in string \abc/there\abc/
Found keyword \abc/, in string \abc/\abc/
```

Comment: Thank you on this, but would you give me another example that is like this: @"\abc/something\abc/\abc/something\abc/,  and return 2 matches of  \abc/something\abc/

Comment: `(?:.*?(\\abc/something\\abc/))+` and use the code above. Or `(?:.*?(\\abc/something\\abc/)){2}` if you want exactly 2 and use the code above.

Comment: how do you represent the 'something' with?   if I use .*  to say any characters in between \abc/  \abc/,   the entire string can match this.  Ideas?

Comment: `.*?` in the example will not match the entire string, only up to the next 'something'. If no something, no match. You can select a starting position too. But, this all means nothing without context.

Comment: The important thing is that CaptureCollection _IS_ the defacto way to do variable amount of capture buffers. That's the point !!

Comment: example:  if my string is :  \abc/somethinghere\abc/\abc/nothinghere\abc/,  will this regex still work so that it finds 2 matches of "\abc/****\abc/" ?

Comment: For _first_ and _last_ only ? Sure. But you wouldn't really need capturecollection for that. I mean, you can use it, with a modification.

Comment: regex.matches(input, pattern) returns a matchcollection and that should work.  but i'm having trouble coming up with this regex so that it gives me two matches of \abc/****\abc/   instead of entire  \abc/***\abc/\abc/****\abc/

Comment: @Mithelee - Added different sample's.